# Question on XSLT noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Tags: biztalk, xslt, biztalk-2010

My incoming XML has the following

```
<ROOT-PARENT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ASR_V3.0.1_proposed.xsd">
```

I am using a Inline XSLT in Scripting Functoid in BizTalk 2010

I want to navigate one of the child nodes but I am unable to get the values. Do i need to

My XSLT looks like

```
<EXTERNALTAG xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ASR_V3.0.1_proposed.xsd">
     <xsl:for-each select ="//MILESTONES/MILESTONE">
          <P><xsl:value-of select="."/></P> 
     </xsl:for-each>
</EXTERNALTAG>
```

The above doesn't seem to work. Any idea what i need to do in order to take care of the 
`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`

Thanks in advance

Karthik

Comment: I don't understand why you want that XML Schema attribute in your output when it's actually in your input... But if you output a prefixed attribute's name, then you must add the namespace declaration in order to make the output a well formed XML document.

Comment: I got it figured out now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. If my XSLT looks like this

`<EXTERNALTAG> <xsl:for-each select ="//MILESTONES/MILESTONE"> <P><xsl:value-of select="."/></P> </xsl:for-each> </EXTERNALTAG>`

everything is working fine

Thanks

Comment: **It's an XML parsing error to use undeclared namespace.** In order to correct such error, you need to declare this namespace or not to use it.